# To reduce the resistance

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

In the circuit I need to find out equivalence Resistance.
[image]

I have applied the Kirchhoff theorem and  but these  look too broad and might take too much time to solve. Is there any easy way to solve it?>

**EDIT:**
So if the vertical resistor doesn't apply any affect to the voltage then the equivalent resistance will be,
$$1/(R_e)=1/2R+1/2R+1/2R$$
That means
$$R_e=2/3R$$
. Is it right?? but the question is why the vertical resistor is not applying voltage changes to the circuit??? Are they acting as only voltage divisor, nothing else?

Comment: Yeah, your intuition is correct, there are real shortcuts. You should be able to solve it by inspection if you take symmetry into account. See one of the suggested solutions to this problem: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105207/how-do-you-arrange-six-6-ohm-resistors-to-have-a-total-resistance-of-6-ohm

Comment: They have answered a particular question. Can you please apply-the symmetry in this circuit then I will get clearly. I'm saying this because they have not explained much :(

Comment: As a gendankenexperiment, leave out the vertical R's. Assuming the battery is 0V, What is the voltage on each of the (remaining) R/R junctions?

Comment: If the battery is zero volts then how can we get the voltage across these resistors? Will they 0 volts too right?

Comment: What Wouter is implying I'll say a different way - what current is flowing thru the vertical resistors - ask your self what voltage would appear on each node of the vertical resistors. This is a strongish hint.

Comment: @Andy aka. actually i applied the Kirchhoff law and indicated the current in my convenient way.  So, if $i_1$ and $i_2$ currents are flowing through  the vertical resistors  the the voltage will  be, $i_1R$ and $i_2R$. Am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Step back and just think about the voltages - if the vertical resistors were removed, what can you say about the voltages on the nodes - I'm not using any math - I'm using observation.

Comment: If there are no vertical resistor then voltage on the nodes will be same because resistance are equal.

Comment: @Andy aka, Am I right?

Comment: @zero_field exactly. And even if you add the vertical resistors, the voltages will be equal. So, what does that imply for the current through the vertical resistors? And what does *that* imply for the equivalent resistance of the entire system?

Comment: @zero_field Correct and read what arne says too.

Comment: The hidden idea everyone is hinting at here is that because of the certain things in this circuit being symmetrical, you don't have to work out voltages and currents in detail. Instead, there are certain branches that have no effect (or might as well be plain wires), and the rest can be viewed as just simple parallel and series combinations of resistors that you can reduce in your head to a single value.

Comment: So if the vertical resistor doesn't apply any affect to the voltage then the equivalent resistance will be, 
$$1/(R_e) = 1/ 2R + 1/2R +1/2R  $$ 
That means $$R_e = 2/3 R $$ . Is it right??  

but the question is why the vertical resistor is not applying  voltage changes to the circuit??? Are they acting as only voltage divisor, nothing else?

Comment: @Andyaka , is my expression correct?

Comment: You are correct - when a resistor hasn't got a voltage across it then the two nodes can be optionally shorted or open-circuited (this applied to passive circuits only and sometimes doesn't apply when actives elements are involved). Well done on allowing folk to tease this from you!! The vertical resistors don't take current and can be short circuits or open circuits. Now try and envisage a cube made from 1 ohm resistors - apply the same techniques and you get an easy (ish) answer!!!

Comment: Can you please  elaborate a little why the vertical resistor will  not take any current?  If the value of these vertical resistor are different like R, and 2R then  Will we have still no current through it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great way to look at a problem where all resistances are equivalent:

1. **Intuition:** Lets (temporarily) remove the vertical resistors and attempt to analyze the problem. After removing the vertical resistors, lets look at what elements exist at the nodes of the voltage source:

   - Connected between both nodes are **3 branches in parallel**
   - Inside of each branch are **2 resistors in series**.

   Since all three branches are identical, lets look at only a single branch first. Lets call the node in between the two resitors "MiddleNode". We apply voltage division and we find that that voltage at MiddleNode is 0.5*Vsource (because both resistors are identical).

   *Note that the MiddleNode voltage is identical on each of the three branches*.

   So if we look at the potential difference (voltage drop) between two MiddleNodes, we find that the voltage drop will be 0V. If you have a 0V potential difference between two nodes (two MiddleNodes in our case), no current will flow through an element placed there. Hence, the vertical resistors play no role.
2. **Solution:** You have 3 branches in parallel with 2R resistance per branch.

   2R//2R//2R = (2/3)R